# dependent types without helper type

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20, dependent-type

Given `typename T` and `int N`, the templated value below generates a null function pointer of the type:

```
int (*) (T_0, ..., T_N)
```

While the code works, I don't like that it pollutes the namespace with the `Temp` bootstrap helper - `Temp` is required because types can't be enclosed in parentheses. For example, none of the following are valid.

```
(int (*)((int))
((int (*)(int)))
(int (*)( (I,T)... ))
```

The last entry shows how I would like to expand `T` into a list of `N` `T`s - which of course isn't valid. It's a trick to make `T` depend on `I` but with a value only of `T`, thanks to the comma operator.

As a workaround, I'm forced to create the one-shot type `Temp` templated to make `T` depend on `int`, or in this case, `I`. Its usage as `Temp<T,I>` is valid because it doesn't enclose types in parenthesis.

However, like I said, I want to get rid of `Temp` because it pollutes the namespace. In the code below I restate the problem and demonstrate some attempted workarounds which sadly, all fail. For the record, I think an equivalence between `template <typename T, int> using Temp = T;` and `template <... template<typename T1, int N1> typename Temp=T>` should be allowed.

*Followup*: When I original published this question, I didn't know exactly why extra parentheses were disallowed, and I'm still not sure why some of my attempts failed. For example:

```
decltype(w<T,N>())...
result_of<w<T,N>()>::type...
```

I don't see any parentheses around types!

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>


// Problem, #1
// This is a one-shot helper than pollutes the namespace
template <typename T, int>
using Temp = T;

// Idea #1
//  Make the one-shot helper actuall useful, where ... represents either
//  type or non-type parameters.
// Result
//  Not possible.
//template <typename T, ...>
//using Dependent = T;

// Idea #2
//  Make the types dependent within the template declaration
// Result
//  Probably not possible
//template <typename T, int N, template<typename T1, int N1> typename F=T>

// Idea #6
//  Replace the lambda with a struct (not shown)
// Result
//  Crashes gcc
template <typename T, int N>
auto a =
    []<size_t... I>
    (std::index_sequence<I...>) { 
        // Problem #2
        //  Function type declaration won't parse with extra parentheses
        //return (int (*)( (I,T)... ))nullptr;

        // Idea #3
        //  Move the templated helper into the function
        // Result
        //  Not possible
        //template <typename T, int>
        //using Temp = T;

        // Idea #4
        //  Replace the templated helper with a templated lambda which *is*
        //  allowed inside functions.
        // Result
        //  Still requires parentheses, still breaks function type declaration
        //auto w = []<typename T1, int N1>() -> T1 {};
        //return (int (*)( decltype(w<T,N>())... ));

        // Idea #5
        //  result_of (which is a template) instead of decltype
        // Result
        //  Doesn't work even without parentheses, not sure why
        //return (int (*)( result_of<w<T,N>>... ));
        //return (int (*)( result_of<w<T,N>()>::type... ));

        // Idea #7
        //  Use std::function
        // Result
        //  Can't get function pointer from std::function

        // Idea #2 implementation
        //using F<T,I> = T;
        //return (int (*)( F<T,I>... ))nullptr;

        // So far, only this works:
        return (int (*)( Temp<T,I>... ))nullptr;
    }
    (std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

int main () {
    auto b = a<int, 4>;
    std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Get rid of `Temp`.

Comment: No, that's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I mean, what is the _actual problem_ you're trying to solve? I don't even understand what `Temp` is doing here, what do you intend `a<int, 4>` to be? There's no description in this question.

Comment: *"Function type declarations won't parse extra parentheses"* What? Can you show some code that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: `Temp<T,I>...` - Are you trying to generate N parameters of the same type using `index_sequence`? You should've started your question with that.

Comment: @Barry, `a<int, 4>` is `(int (*)(int, int, int, int)nullptr`. It is working as intended using `Temp`, but I think `Temp` is ugly and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: You can always hide `Temp` away in a `detail` namespace or something

Comment: *So far, only this works* <-- Maybe a good idea to explain what **this** is.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, For example neither `(int (*)( (int) )` nor `((int (*)(int)))` will compile.

Comment: @user19087 Okay so the goal really is to have `a<T, N>` give you a pointer to function that returns `int` and takes `N` parameters of type `T`? And should probably be an alias template, not a variable template?

Comment: Ok, and what is the goal? Given `typename T, int N`, generate what? A type `int(*)(T.../*N times*/)`?

Comment: @Barry, HolyBlackCat: yes

Comment: It would be helpful if you put that in the question then.

Comment: Yep, IMHO it should be clearly stated at the beginning of the question, then the successful attempt, then something like "I don't like that it pollutes the namespace".

Comment: @Barry, HolyBlackCat: Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace `Temp<T,I>` with `std::enable_if_t<(void(I), true), T>`.

---

> Function type declarations won't parse extra parentheses

> that actually works! Why?

Types can't be enclosed in parentheses. But the first argument of `enable_if_t` is an expression rather than a type, so `( )` is allowed there.

Comment: Not sure, but if this works....

Comment: Not the downvoter, but maybe this needs more context, like where this is supposed to be used. I imagine it's a stand-in replacement for `Temp<T,I>` in the OP's current solution? So `return (int (*)( std::enable_if_t<(I, true), T>... ))nullptr;`?

Comment: @Kevin Yep, this replaces `Temp<T,I>`.

Comment: Because this isn't an answer, it's a comment. And it's only an answer in the very narrow sense that it helps OP on the path they found themselves on, but it's not actually a good solution to the problem.

Comment: I feel like the question deserve a downvote more then this answer...

Comment: Wow, that actually works! Why? I tried `std::result_of` which has parenthesis within the `<>`, but that wouldn't compile. This answer also has parentheses within `<>` but still works...

Comment: FTR I would cast `I` to `void` to avoid the warnings. Can you explain why your answer works whereas my attempts failed?

Comment: @Barry I argue that a short answer is still an answer (not necessarily a good answer). Anyhow, edited. *"not actually a good solution to the problem"* If the problem is "generate such-and-such type", I think OP's solution is decent. I don't see much room for improvement, except I'd maybe use a partially specialized struct instead of a lamdbda.

Comment: @user19087 Added the cast, and a short explanation. Types can't be enclosed in parentheses, but expressions can. And the first argument of `enable_if_t` is an expression rather than a type.

Comment: 'Types can't be enclosed in parentheses'. I don't really understand this. I updated my answer, and two of my attempts don't enclose types in parentheses. Can you explain this in more detail, or link to an explanation, or something?

Comment: @user19087 `w<T,N>()` doesn't work because `w`, being a lambda, is not a template. Only it's `operator()` is a template, and there's no way to specify its template arguments without using the `operator()` notation. So, something like `w.template operator()<T, N>()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy with [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_repeat_cl_n):

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
using into_func = int(Args...);

template <typename T, size_t N>
using result = mp_apply<func_type, mp_repeat_c<mp_list<T>, N>>;
```

`mp_repeat_c<mp_list<T>, N>` gives us `mp_list<T, T, T, ..., T>` with `N` parameters, and then we `mp_apply` `into_func` on that, which turns it into the function type we want.

---

As to why a few of your other versions didn't work:

This one:

```cpp
decltype(w<T,N>())...
```

where:

```cpp
auto w = []<typename T1, int N1>() -> T1 {};
```

That's not how you call that lambda. The call operator is a template, but you can't provide the template parameters like that. You have to write `w.operator()<T, N>()`. If you did that, that probably works.

Or you could do:

```cpp
auto w = [](size_t) -> T { };
```

And then use `decltype(w(N))...`.

Although it would be better to write something closer to a valid lambda, like:

```cpp
auto w = [](size_t) { return std::type_identity<T>{}; };
```

And then use `typename decltype(w(N))::type...`

---

This approach:

```cpp
result_of<w<T,N>()>::type...
```

`result_of` is used like `result_of<F(Args...)>` where `F` is a function or function object type. For instance:

```cpp
struct F { double operator()(int); };
result_of_t<F(int)>; // this is double
```

This just isn't anything like that here at all - it's just a misuse of `result_of`. `result_of` is also deprecated in favor of `invoke_result`, which wouldn't work with this lambda as specified anyway since again it takes template parameters rather than function parameters.

With my last rewrite tho:

```cpp
typename std::invoke_result_t<decltype(w), decltype(N)>::type...
```

Note both the `decltype(w)` (since you need a type, not an object) and the `decltype(N)` (since again, type not value).